# Не добовляется валюта к базе данных sql discord.py

Tags: python, mysql, sql, discord.py

Деньги убирает,Но апргейд не суммируется,почему так незнаю :c

```
@client.command()
    async def upgrade(ctx):
      cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET upgrade = upgrade + upgrade WHERE id = {}".format(10,ctx.author.id))
      cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - 100 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
      connection.commit()
      await ctx.send('улучшено')
```

Comment: `cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET upgrade = upgrade + upgrade WHERE id = {}".format(10,ctx.author.id))` зачем тут 10 ?

Comment: я уже давно сделал